Can't get DBeaver to read my ssh key (permission error)
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, on a Legion laptop.
I'm using DBeaver, a DB GUI. I had all my connections set up, all using the same ssh key I'm trying to set up now. A large script caused DBeaver to crash, and when it loaded back up, it gave me an error about another instance already using the workspace. Being an idiot, I deleted the workspace, but of course that means I lost all my connections. When I try to set up my connections again, I get a Exhausted all available authentication methods error, and the logs show
Could not load keys from /home/my_home/.ssh/id_ecdsa due to: /home/my_home/.ssh/id_ecdsa (Permission denied)

The permissions weren't changed. The folder is 700, and the file is 500, which I believe is the recommendation. I tried making the file 544 just to see if it would do anything, but no luck. No idea what permissions issue has arisen, nor how to figure it out. The app is installed via snap, if it matters.

Which snap, exactly? you may need to enable the snap ssh-keys interface - see for example Dbeaver CE Ubuntu snap can't read SSH key in ~/.ssh

Sorry, when you say what "which snap", what do you mean? The version? Or is there another piece of information I can help provide? I'll take a look at ssh-keys and the linked issue.

I just meant the name of the snap - I am not familiar with DBeaver and wasn't sure whether dbeaver-ce was the only available snap for it

@steeldriver Yah, that's the one.
